# How does MsBuild match wildcards in Exclude attribute on items?

Tags: msbuild

What is the exact behavior of the Exclude attribute with wildcards on items in item collection? In some cases it works as I would expect, and in other cases it fails to exclude apparently matching files.

Suppose I have an `src/` subdirectory, containing a few subdirectories on its own. Let's call them `src/base` and `src/util` (really there are quite a few, 20+). My intent is to compile all files from selected subdirectories of `src/`, except files ending in `-test.cc`. Suppose, without loss of generality, that there exists a file `src/base/io-test.cc`.

In the two cases below the path (sans filename) in `Include` and `Exclude` attributes is the same, and the file `src/base/io-test.cc` is excluded as expected: The first, as anticipated, includes non-test files only from `src/base`:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ClCompile Include="src/base/*.cc" Exclude="src/base/*-test.cc" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and the second all non-test files from all subdirectories of `src/`:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ClCompile Include="src/*/*.cc" Exclude="src/*/*-test.cc" />
</ItemGroup>
```

But the following *does not* exclude files seemingly matching the `Exclude` pattern:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ClCompile Include="src/base/*.cc" Exclude="src/*/*-test.cc" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I would expect the `src/base/io-test.cc` file excluded, as its name clearly matches the pattern (and actually excluded by it in the second case), but the file is included in the collection.

[MSDN is somewhat vague on the Exclude behavior.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx#Anchor_4) Strict reading might even suggest that wildcards are not supported in it at all, but I do not believe this is the case.

Since my intention is to include files from a few *listed* directories (akin to `Include="src/base/*.cc;src/util/*.cc"`) but exclude *all* test files, the last definition is the one that I am trying to get working.

Comment: I tried this with VS2015 and it seems to work fine. Could you please share the full test project file that you are trying? BTW, keep in mind that the Exclude only works on the items being added by the corresponding Include in the *same* item element as the Exclude.

Comment: @radical: Interesting. I'll work on a shortened version. Cannot share a 2K file real thing, of course.

Comment: Is the use of .cc and .cpp extensions in the sample filenames mixed up here unintentionally?

Comment: @StayOnTarget, thank you, it's a typo indeed. If you don't mind sharing your opinion, MSBuild has changed so much since 2016 that I don't see how the Q could be relevant today. I considered deleting it, as it has got no answers anyway; on the other hand, excluding Qs without As is a doddle; on the gripping hand, its historical significance is dubious at best. And as SO ages, noise keeps piling up. Whad'ya think, or ?

Comment: @kkm-stillwaryofSEpromises as it happens I work with some old technology regularly and sometimes questions about it here are the best (or only) source of info. That can make these older questions actually more valuable with time.  I would suggest editing the question and/or tags just to note the version of MSBuild for which it is relevant.

Comment: @StayOnTarget Thanks for your thoughts! I'll try to do just that.